# Issue manipulating the Spreadsheet connected to a Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Sorry if this question has been answered before, I did not find any entries with this issue. I'm trying to set up a newsletter subscription service for our non-profit organisation.

I'm using a Google Form to collect user input. OnFormSubmit a script on the form is to write additional information into the connected Spreadsheet.

Problem: I am unable to call the Spreadsheet:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveSheet" of null.

Do I need to initialise the Spreadsheet or must I create the Script outside of the Form?

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
```

Is it possible to manipulate the Spreadsheet which is collecting the Form input via the Form Google Script?

This is the code behind the Google Form which is set to run onFormSubmit:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) { 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
  var sheet = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]); 
  var row = sheet.getLastRow(); sheet.getRange(row,4).setValue(row); 
}
```

Comment: Could you paste your code here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, @amit-agarwal ! 
The code is very basic: This is the code behind the Google Form which is set to run onFormSubmit:

function onFormSubmit(e) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
var row =  sheet.getLastRow();

sheet.getRange(row,4).setValue(row);
}

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to paste the code in the script editor of the responses spreadsheet. You are probably using it inside Forms.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to get me one step further. I am trying to insert the editResponseLink into the Spreadsheet using this code:

Do you see my mistake?  
  
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
 var sheet = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);   
 var row = sheet.getLastRow();  
 var linkurl = 6;  
 sheet.getRange(row,linkurl).setValue(response.getEditResponseUrl());     
Many thanks!

Comment: var response = e.response;   
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
var sheet = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);  var row = sheet.getLastRow(); var linkurl = 6;  sheet.getRange(row,linkurl).setValue(response.getEditResponseUrl());

Comment: Or do I need a different solution to access the response.editResponseUrl() by the script inside the Spreadsheet?

Thanks and sorry for the confusion. @amit

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot! I used this description for the rest of my requirement: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/LSKKCR3VHC8

Comment: Ales see this snippet http://ctrlq.org/code/19986-edit-response-url-in-google-sheets